# I'm trying to export data from a dictionary list into a data frame but i keep getting this error: invalid index to scalar variable

Tags: python-3.x

I just want to have the dictionary's key and values in a data frame.

```
ETA_pred = []

for pred in ETA_predictions:
    ETA_pred.append(pred['predictions'][0])
```

or

```
ETA_pred = []

for pred in ETA_predictions:
    ETA_pred.append(pred['predictions'][0:])
```

Dictionary values:

```
ETA_predictions = [{'predictions': array([57.953255], dtype=float32)},
                   {'predictions': array([53.815216], dtype=float32)},
                   {'predictions': array([51.187553], dtype=float32)},
                   {'predictions': array([30.357912], dtype=float32)},
                   {'predictions': array([52.69792],  dtype=float32)},]
```